# ChartJS unable to register global plugin

Tags: javascript, chart.js

After a ChartJS migration from v2 to v3 i'm unable to registed a global plugin, by following the migration guide i changed `Chart.plugins.register` in `Chart.register` but i get this:

> class does not have id: function (chart)

The issue i think is in afterDraw function but how should it be fixed after a migration?

The code

```
Chart.register({
    afterDraw: function (chart) {
        var data = chart.data.datasets[0].data;
        if (data.length === 0) {
            // No data is present
            var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
            var width = chart.chart.width;
            var height = chart.chart.height
            chart.clear();

            ctx.save();
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
            ctx.font = "16px normal 'Helvetica Nueue'";
            ctx.fillText('Nessun dato disponibile', width / 2, height / 2);
            ctx.fontColor = "#828282";
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the documentation better a [unique id must be configured for each registered plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.4.1/developers/plugins.html#plugin-id).

> Plugins must define a unique id in order to be configurable.

So i just added the id in my code

```
Chart.register({
    id: 'no_data_label',
    afterDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
        const data = chart.data.datasets[0].data;
        if (data.length === 0) {
            // No data is present
            console.log(chart)
            const current = chart.ctx;
            const width = chart.width;
            const height = chart.height
            chart.clear();

            current.save();
            current.textAlign = 'center';
            current.textBaseline = 'middle';
            current.font = "16px normal 'Helvetica Nueue'";
            current.fillText('Nessun dato disponibile', width / 2, height / 2);
            current.fontColor = "#828282";
            current.restore();
        }
    }
});
```